# Converting an MVC controller to Async

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I have a controller like this :

```
public ActionResult MainController()

/*do stuff*/

JsonResult jsonresult;
return jsonresult;
```

I'm trying to make this Async like this :

```
public async Task MainController()

/*do stuff*/   

JsonResult jsonresult;
return /*I don't know what to write*/
```

I have searched SO and some other sites but I couldn't find a solution. As I saw, `FromResult` is used but when I used it, I got errors. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the action method to look like this and you can return your inital result again:

public async Task<ActionResult> MainController()

btw: the name of the action is a bit strange... ;)

Comment: It looks like the constructor for the Main controller now.